# How do I test this?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm new to Jest and react-testing-library, so hopefully the solution to this is straight forward.

What is the proper way to test the value returned through the 'onChange' prop?

```
    describe("Component.js", () => {
        test("return correct data", () => {
            render(
                <Component
                    onChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
                />
            );
        });
    });
```

I would like to do something like this for 'value'.

```
expect(value).toBe(50);
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's say Component.js looks something like this.

```
const Component = ({onChange}) => {
   return (
      <button onClick={() => onChange(50)}></button>
   )
}
```

Comment: Which even inside `Component.js` fires this `onChange` method? or Could you show us your  `Component.js`?

Comment: Updated with some additional details. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
const Component = ({onChange}) => {
    return (
        <button onClick={() => onChange(50)}>CustomButton</button>
    )
}

describe("Component.js", () => {
    test("return correct data", () => {
        const onChangeHandler = jest.fn();
        render(
            <Component onChange={onChangeHandler} />
        );
        fireEvent.click(
           screen.getbyText(/CustomButton/)
        );
        expect(onChangeHandler).toBeCalledWith(50);
    });
});
```

The above may need modifications to be adopted to your use case.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work. "onDateChange" should be "onChangeHandler" I assume?

Comment: Yep, fixed now. Thanks! @JakeLong

Answer (score 0):

just pass the component a mock function and test if it was called when the button is changed (though I assume for a button you would use onClick). You may need to add a testId or some way to target the button in your component as well.

```
describe("Component.js", () => {
  test("return correct data", () => {
  const spy = jest.fn();
    render(
      <Component
        onChange={spy}
      />
    );
    fireEvent.change(screen.getByTestId('button'));
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(50);
  });
});
```

and the component

```
const Component = ({onChange}) => {
  return (
    <button 
      data-testid = 'button' 
      onClick={() => onChange(50)}></button>
  )
}
```